# AWS invalid policy - terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating a policy and a role for API gateway to access dynamodb api endpoints with below terraform config. What am I missing? I am getting invalid policy error on `terraform plan`

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "api_dbaccess_policy" {
  name = "api_dbaccess_policy"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.apiGatewayDynamoDbAccessRole.id}"

  policy = <<EOF
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchGet*",
                "dynamodb:DescribeStream",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                "dynamodb:Get*",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:BatchWrite*",
                "dynamodb:CreateTable",
                "dynamodb:Delete*",
                "dynamodb:Update*",
                "dynamodb:PutItem"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
  }
  EOF

  # depends_on = [ 
  #   "aws_dynamodb_table.us-east-1"
  # ]
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "apiGatewayDynamoDbAccessRole" {
  name = "apiGatewayDynamoDbAccessRole"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
  {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
          {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "Service": [
                  "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
              ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
              }
      ]
      }
  EOF
}
```

What am i doing wrong? I am getting invalid policy error.

Comment: Your HEREDOC shouldn't be indented

Comment: read: "remove the spaces prior to `EOF` in the second to last line

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, just remove the indention in the `EOF` block...

Another option is to use the [`aws_iam_policy_document`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/iam_policy_document.html) data source. For me it is a cleaner approach and is better maintainable, e.g. when you are using an IDE with terraform support.
Your config would look like this (`"Effect": "Allow"` is not needed here, because it's default behavior):

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "api_dbaccess_policy" {
  name = "api_dbaccess_policy"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.apiGatewayDynamoDbAccessRole.id}"

  policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.dynamodb.json}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "apiGatewayDynamoDbAccessRole" {
  name = "apiGatewayDynamoDbAccessRole"

  assume_role_policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.apigateway.json}"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "dynamodb" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "dynamodb:BatchGet*",
      "dynamodb:DescribeStream",
      "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
      "dynamodb:Get*",
      "dynamodb:Query",
      "dynamodb:Scan",
      "dynamodb:BatchWrite*",
      "dynamodb:CreateTable",
      "dynamodb:Delete*",
      "dynamodb:Update*",
      "dynamodb:PutItem"
    ]

    resources = ["*"]
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "apigateway" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["apigateway.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}
```